# How would you translate say "Oh my god! You could be my little sister" in German?

Tags: english-to-german

Just as the title says. I would like to sound as natural as possible!

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language. To get your question re-opened please [edit] it to give us an idea of what you tried, and where you believe you need help. Some translation request also may need a bit of context. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the context in which you're going to use it, but the translation is rather straight forward:

> Oh mein Gott! Du könntest meine kleine Schwester sein.

Alternatively, if you mean she looks like your younger sister, you could also say (sounds more natural):

> Oh mein Gott! Du siehst aus wie meine kleine Schwester.

Comment: Instead of "Oh mein Gott!" people often use "(Ach du) meine Güte!" because *thou shalt not take in vain.* A colloquial alternative is "Meine Fresse!"

Comment: @Janka - "...because *thou shalt not take in vain.*" - I know you may be over-playing that, but do Germans really try to avoid using it? In the USA, which is generally speaking a pretty religious country, saying "Oh my God" is pretty commonplace.  Just curious if in German, they really do try to avoid using it more often than say US English.

Comment: I've never heard more *oh my god* swears than from U.S. americans. "Oh mein Gott!" is pretty much reserved to fatal failures and people who watched too many too literally dubbed U.S. sitcoms. German speakers mainly use a broader variation of swears because "Oh mein Gott" sounds just akward and clunky. "Ach du meine Güte" is for people who don't want to swear, explicitely.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: People in Europe (including all countries where German is spoken) are way less religious than people in the USA. So you generally should try to use fewer religious terms in colloquial speech when speaking German. But there are exceptions: In the south of German sprachraum (i.e. Bavaria and Austria) the salutation »Grüß Gott« (*may god greet you*) is very common. Also very common: »Gottseidank« (*thank god*) and »Oh Gott!« (*Oh Lord!*). The term »Oh mein Gott« (*oh my god*) is still well known, but less common. You better learn: OMG! = »Meine Güte!« (*My goodness!*)